# Is there a way to solve initializing local variables in structures?

Tags: c, initialization

So my group has been assigned to make a class schedule that registers the user (inputting the course code, offer code, time and day, etc.) and as I was coding, I stumbled upon an error in my `menu` function, that the local variable `classs` is not initialized.

Is there anything I'm missing?

I am a beginner in C and combining pointers, structures and strings altogether is a bit confusing.

Here is the entire code:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<conio.h>
   #include<string.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>

   #define P printf
   #define S scanf

   void menu(struct class_sched *classs, int choice);
   void registerclass (struct class_sched *classs); 

   struct data {  
        char course_code[10];
        int offer_code;
        char course_name[6];
        char room_no[7];
        char faculty_name[30];
        char time[20];
        char day[3];
   };

    struct class_sched {
           struct data sched;
   };                                       

 int main (void){

    int info = 0;
    int choice;
    struct class_sched *classs;

    printf("MENU\n");
    printf("\n[1]Registration \n[2]Checking \n[3]Exit\n");
    S("%d",&choice);

    menu(classs,choice); //the error in question or specified

    getch();
    system("cls");
}

void menu(struct class_sched *classs,int choice){ //the Main Menu for the program

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: 
        registerclass(classs); 
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void registerclass (struct class_sched *classs){ // for registering or the inputs for the user

        P("Registration \n");
        P("input: \nCourse Code: "); fflush(stdin); gets(classs->sched.course_code);
        P("Offer Code: "); fflush(stdin);S("%d",&classs->sched.offer_code);
        P("Course Name: "); fflush(stdin); gets(classs->sched.course_name);
        P("Room Number: "); fflush(stdin); gets(classs->sched.room_no);
        P("Faculty Name: "); fflush(stdin); gets(classs->sched.faculty_name);
        P("Time: "); fflush(stdin); gets(classs->sched.time);
        P("Day: "); fflush(stdin); gets(classs->sched.day);

}
```

Comment: The reason you are getting the undefined error is because you are missing the word "struct" in front of "data" in your "class_sched" struct. Example: "struct data sched;". Alternatively, you could typedef the data struct so that you wouldn't have to explicitly write struct each time.

Comment: regarding: `   struct data 
   {  
        char course_code[10];
        int  offer_code;
        char course_name[6];
        char room_no[7];
        char faculty_name[30];
        char time[20];
        char day[3];
   };` and before that, this: `void menu(struct class_sched *classs, int choice);
   void registerclass (struct class_sched *classs);`  The compiler will complain because the struct is defined AFTER it is used.  Suggest moving the `struct` definition  BEFORE its' usage.

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  The function: `fflush()` is for output streams only, not input streams.  The result (except for visual studio) is undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `gets(classs->sched.course_code)`  The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for decades and completely removed from the C language for the last few releases of the language.  Suggest using: `fgets()`

Comment: OT: regarding: `#define P printf` and 1#define S scanf`  Please do not confuse the reader by replacing the function names with some macro

Comment: regarding: `struct class_sched *classs;`  This declares a pointer, BUT does not point it to memory that the program owns.  Therefore, in the function: `registerclass()`  all attempts to write to any of the fields is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding:  1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: when calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful input format conversions.  In the current code, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`  )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Answer (score 4):

> *[...]  in my "menu" function, that the local variable 'classs' is not initialized. Is there anything I'm missing?*

Yes, you miss to pass in something initialised.

In `main()` the code defines the pointer `classs`

```
 struct class_sched *classs;
```

**without** initialising it.

Then further down the code passes this very (still **uninitialised**) pointer `classs` to `menu()`:

```
 menu(classs, choice); //the error in question or specified
```

This *could* be solved by defining inside `main()` a struct, like so:

```
 struct class_sched classs;
```

and pass to `menu()` its address:

```
 menu(&classs, choice);
```

---

Two other issues:

- [Calling `fflush()` for `stdin` invokes undefined behaviour](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2). Do not do this.
- `gets()` is evil. It allows the user to overflow the input buffer. It also is not part of C any more since long. Use [`fgets()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2) instead.